# What to do with unruly users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Earlier today, a new user posted a [question about a Minecraft crash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198336/when-i-press-the-run-button-then-at-the-bottem-of-all-the-words-is-says-pleas). Being a regular user, I made a couple of touch-ups, edited the title, removed unnecessary tags, etc. This was not received well. I explained myself, clarified the content of the question was not enough for us to go off, etc. This was also not received well.

This happened around three times, with the occasional input from other users. We eventually came to a point where the question was considered irredeemable, because the new user was refusing to comply.

In future, to skip the pointless back and forth that goes no where, what should be done/what should I do/what could we do in these situations?

Comment: In similar questions on other meta sites, I always see the same advice: Only help someone as long as it feels good. At the exact moment it ceases to feel good, stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes some people will just not grasp what you're asking them. Others don't want to and are just trolling. I'm pretty sure this one was one of the latter.

Obviously we're here to provide assistance but if somebody is coming across as though they're not really here for an answer, and are just causing trouble then there isn't really anything we can do about them directly; just flag for moderator attention or [bring it up in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) so that somebody with the power to do anything about it can take action.